# Dynamically importing SCSS in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, tsc

I've used Create React App (CRA) to set up a new project, then added `node-sass` to be able to import SCSS files.

**Example:**

```js
import "./App.scss";
```

While this works fine, I cannot load styles asynchronously using `import()`. I've used this technique in a pure JavaScript project, but since converting it TypeScript I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot find module './fallback.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307

Here's a MVE of the code producing the problem:

```
async function loadFallbackStyles(): Promise<void> {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.includes("Trident/")) {
        await import("./fallback.scss");
    }
}
```

I've already tried adding `declare module "*.scss"` to my type declarations, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `declare module "*.scss"` will work, when it's in the correct declarations file. I've put it in `global.d.ts` and the error went away.

I'm still wondering why static imports worked out of the box, so feel free to post a more in-depth answer!

Answer (score 1):

[idleberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65809464/8093394) pointed me in right direction when I was struggling with something similar, so let me share it for anyone who faces the same problem and the trick with the `global.d.ts` doesn't work:

##### Context

I'm adding typescript to an existing react SPA. In some pages, there is a use of [Dynamic Import](https://hy.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) to load content from a couple of `md` files.

Imports was like this:

```
const dynamicLoadContentPromise = import('../path/to/file.md')
```

When trying to migrate that page from `jsx` to `tsx`, these `import`s resulted in a compilation error:

> Cannot find module '../path/to/file.md' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

##### Fix

Thanks to the discussion on [this issue on github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/2883#issuecomment-365864950), I figured out that creating a file `typings.d.ts` declaring the extension fix the issue:

```
declare module "*.md" {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

It made the whole thing works again.